# Retrieving data in span using jQuery which is inserted into using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have inserted a div with some text into a parent div tag on add button click on client side. Now I want to retrieve same data client side when I tried to find the element which i just inserted using 'id' it is returning me null.

Some how i want to get this information on client side send it back to the controller on another button click event I don't want ajax here. I am using Asp.net MVC.

Thanks for the help.

```
function addActor() {
        var actor = $("#Actor_Name").val();


        var ni = document.getElementById('added_Movies');
        var numi = document.getElementById('theIncrementor');
        var num = (document.getElementById('theIncrementor').value - 1) + 2;
        numi.value = num;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        var divIdName = 'my' + num + 'Div';
        newdiv.setAttribute('id', divIdName);

        newdiv.innerHTML = "<span id=\"a"+num+"\" style=\"width:150px; float:left;\">" + actor + "</span> &nbsp; <a href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"removeActor(\'" + divIdName + "\')\">Remove </a>";
        ni.appendChild(newdiv);
    }
```

This happens on add button

on submit I have to loop through to get all the inserted data and send it to my controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a class to the newly created spans and then get those spans using

```
$("span.classname").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
});
```

***Suggestion***

You can change the current javascript code to jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Your code would really help here but I'll wing it...

```
$('#parentDiv').append($("<div id='myInsertedDiv'>Hello!</div>"));

$('#myInsertedDiv').html(); // -> "Hello!"

/* OR */

$('#parentDiv div').html() // -> "Hello!"
```

Comment: When I do this it is returning me null... I can't see the added html on view source

Comment: You will not be able to see dynamically added content in page view source. You can inspect that using firebug or any other debugging utility that can inspect live DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Relying on innerHTML for retrieval of your data is messy (it will return markup if you need to add child elements for styling or layout, etc).  I recommend using jQuery's data method instead (also you are mixing native and jquery dom methods, so I have edited a bit):

```
function addActor() {
        var self = this;
        var actor = $("#Actor_Name").val();
        var ni = $('#added_Movies');
        var num = $('#theIncrementor').val();
        var newdiv = $('<div id="my'+num+'Div" class="actorDiv"/>')
            .data("actor", actor);
        var newspan = $('<span id="a'+num+'">actor </span>')
            .css({
                "width":"150px", // you should be doing this in an external stylesheet unless you need computed values for these attributes
                "float":"left"
            });
        var removeLink = $('<a href="javascript:void(0)">Remove</a>')
            .click(function(){
                removeActor("my"+self.num+"Div");
            });
        newdiv.append(newspan, removeLink);
        ni.append(newdiv);
        $('#theIncrementor').val(num++);
    }
```

Then on submit you will want to loop through your divs and pull that actor data value:

```
function getActors() {
    var result = [];
    $('.actorDiv').each(function(){
        result.push(this.data("actor"));
    });
    return result;
}
```

The advantage of doing it this way is you can continue to associate custom data with the dom elements in case you need to add more variables, and your results cannot be polluted with markup.